# Error message "the program can't start becuse MSVCP110.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: command-line

I got the message "the program can't start becuse MSVCP110.dll is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem" when i Run wamp server.

Comment: & did you try reinstalling it?

Answer (score 3):

`msvcp110.dll` is part of the [Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). Since your applications are most likely x86 binaries, you’ll need the x86 version. Doesn’t hurt to install both, though.